# Get CPU load statistic from apache access log

Tags: apache, apache-log-files

I have apache access log, i want to parse it and to get top CPU load pages and agents. Does somebody know good script for this? My log line has this format:

> host.ru 11.11.111.11 - - [01/Apr/2018:11:59:22 +0300] "GET
>   /page?action=edit HTTP/1.1" 200 10142 "-" "MauiBot
>   (crawler.feedback+wc@gmail.com)" 303012 299999:0

299999:0 - is the user:system CPU time.